# Grails: Creating XML nodes with variables

Tags: xml, grails, groovy, markupbuilder

I can't seem to figure out how to create nodes that are not hardcoded. Example:

```
def aval = "someValue" 
def xml = new MarkupBuilder()

xml.outTag(attr: aval)   // outTag is hardcoded
```

My problem is: what if I don't know the name of the node (like in my example, what if I want the outTag to be a variable). I'm using this when I read a directory/files and create an XML from it. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this format:

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

def dynamicTag = "blah"
def aval = "someValue"
def xml = new MarkupBuilder()

xml."$dynamicTag"(attr: aval)
```

This worked for me (Groovy 1.8)

Comment: Thanks. That worked. For some weird reason, I could not find this is any tutorial. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Great!  Since this worked, please mark this response as "Accepted"!

Comment: The reason why it works is that you can call any method with the dynamic notation object."$methodName" where methodName is a string variable with the name of the method as value